# How to get path to bash script independent of whether it is sourced from bash or from another script?

Tags: bash

I have a script, that configures some environment variables. Therefore it needs its own position, the value of $0.

I have another script that sources the first script, but it could also happen that the first script is sourced from the console.

However, neither `$0`, nor `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` seem to work consistently on MacOS. Here is a small example to show what I mean:

a.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
source ./b.sh
```

b.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
echo "$0"
echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
```

Output of `./a.sh`:

```
./a.sh
./b.sh
```

Output of `source ./b.sh`:

```
./b.sh
<empty line, can't get stackoverflow to display it properly>
```

Not relevant, but just for completeness: output of `./b.sh`:

```
./b.sh
./b.sh
```

So, in short: If I use `$0` to get the script name, it is wrong when sourced via another script. If I use `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}`, it will be empty when sourced directly.

How can I get the script name in both cases?

Comment: I don't really agree that this is a duplicate question. Yes, the question is how to get the source directory, which is answered in the referred question. However, as far as I saw, they use either `$0` or `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` in all the answers, which both don't work for my case. So my question is not actually answered in the referred question.

Comment: I changed the title to better describe the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that `${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-$0}` resolves to the correct script name in both cases.